# Who is this person in this image?

Tags: grandmaster, fritz, identify-this

I think many chess players saw this image when playing older versions of Fritz as the option "coach is watching." But out of curiosity, who is the person in the image? Is he a grandmaster?

[image: le see this]

Comment: He appears on this book cover too: https://www.junfermann.de/titel/die-tricks-der-trickser/161

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh interesting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like its a stock image: the oldest source of the image I could find from 2008: http://www.grafamania.net/clipart/6201-digital-vision-dv297surreal-business.html